# Bootstrap modal not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have created two modals using Bootstrap and those are opening using jQuery with Ajax requested data. The problem is these modals are working properly on Google Chrome, but not working on Firefox. How do I fix it?

My code is below:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#file_popup", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "fileshare.php",
    method: "post",
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
      $("#tbl_content").html(data);
      jQuery.noConflict();
      $("#pp_filedownload").modal('show');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="pp_filedownload" role="dialog" hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content" style="">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <strong class="modal-title">File Download</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id='tbl_content'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mr.x: Good edit overall, but FWIW it's jQuery, not `jquery`, and proper names like Google and Firefox are initially-capped, not all-lower-case. (If you seem to be getting unusual feedback on your edits, it's probably because of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361353/did-i-not-blockquote-this-correctly) on MSO.)

Comment: When posting your code as a snippet, please make sure that it actually works as a stand-alone snippet here. When I run the snippet, nothing appears, and judging by the JavaScript code, it also doesn’t make much sense to try.

Comment: Why "jQuery.noConflict();" in success callback?

Answer (score 3):

I tried a sample, it works fine in all browsers. Try with this, may be this will help u

```js
//You can launch the modal with the code below this.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitButton").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <input type="submit" id="submitButton"/>

 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: my code is working, but not suddenly, opening page in firefox and after few second it is opening, if not, should refresh the page after first loading. i think  jquery is not response at once. thank you all.